# Javascript array variable when named "name" showing unexpected result when storing strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, variable-names

I am writing a very simple code for storing strings in an array and then splitting it but apparently the "variable name" seems to have an impact on the results.

I have tried this on Google Chrome console as well as Microsoft edge. Results are the same.

```js
var fullName = "Jonathan Archer";
var name = fullName.split(" ");
console.log(name[0]);

//The output of the above code is : "J"

var userName = fullName.split(" ");
console.log(userName[0]);

//The output of the above code is: "Jonathan"

//Also tried following, also exhibited same behavior as above
var name = ["Jonathan", "Archer"];
var userName = ["Jonathan", "Archer"];
console.log(name[0]);
console.log(userName[0]);
```

I don't see why these two code snippets are producing different results. Is there any restriction for using "name" as an array name in JavaScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use `name` as variable name, Because it will conflict with [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

```js
var fullName = "Jonathan Archer";
var n = fullName.split(" ");
console.log(n[0]);

//The output of the above code is : "J"

var userName = fullName.split(" ");
console.log(userName[0]);

//The output of the above code is: "Jonathan"

//Also tried following, also exhibited same behavior as above
var n = ["Jonathan", "Archer"];
var userName = ["Jonathan", "Archer"];
console.log(n[0]);
console.log(userName[0]);
```

Comment: Or just don't use `var`, use `let` or `const`

Comment: Or don't use it in the global scope

Comment: @Olian04 sure :) but what if OP isn't using environment which doesn't support `let and const`

Comment: @Bergi  yeah :) but i will go with using a name other than `name` :)

Comment: So that means `name` is restricted in global scope. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Asif yes if you're using `var`

Comment: Ok got it @CodeManiac thanks for the help!